# Перенос файла pst в Outlook

Tags: outlook, email

Как в Outlook перенести файл pst, который создается для работы почты по IMAP?

Добавлено.Версия Outlook 2010. Файл pst для IMAP создается без возможности указания места расположения. С переносом pst, который работает через pop3, проблем нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос через Junction Point. Чтобы делать через контекстное меню, надо установить [это](http://alax.info/blog/ntfslinks).

Answer (score 0):

MS Outlook 2010

File -> Open -> Import -> Export to a File -> Outlook Data File (.pst)

Comment: Это в какой версии такая последовательность, 2003? У меня 2010.

Comment: Подредактировал. У меня на английском версия, но думаю путь понятен. Уточните для чего нужно переносить файл? Возможно вы хотите не перенести файл, а поменять расположение файла pst, который создается по умолчанию при создании IMAP соединения.

Comment: Да, я  хочу поменять расположение файла по умолчанию. Экспорт мне не нужен, я же по IMAP работаю.